# Why does this jQuery snippet not animate once before it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this jQuery snippet seem to not run the first time around? It doesn't seem to animate when I hover the first time. Does it have to do with binding to the element?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!($.browser.safari || $.browser.chrome)){
        $('.boxgrid').hover(function(){
            $(".boxcaption", this).animate({opacity:'1'},{duration:200});
        }, function() {
            $(".boxcaption", this).animate({opacity:'0'},{duration:350});
        });
    }
});
```

here's the css that accompanies it.

```
.boxcaption{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s linear;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    opacity: 0;
}
.boxgrid:hover .boxcaption{
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: can you share your html source code ?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.  Perhaps if you provide the html as well it will show the problem.  Is the .boxcaption hidden (opacity:0) initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't animate because it's already at 100% opacity until you mouseout. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!($.browser.safari || $.browser.chrome)){

        // Hide .boxcaption
        $('.boxgrid .boxcaption').css({'opacity':0});

        $('.boxgrid').hover(function(){
            $(".boxcaption", this).animate({opacity:'1'},{duration:200});
        }, function() {
            $(".boxcaption", this).animate({opacity:'0'},{duration:350});
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/SXX2D/

**Edit**: Seeing your CSS now, you're probably just experiencing some lag in the rendering. Try with a solid background, it looks fine to me the way it is on FF4.

Comment: If you are browser sniffing, it makes more sense to hide the div with javascript, as it will remain `hidden` if you use CSS and the browser is not supported in your js code.

Comment: maybe it's more to do with css than jquery.

Comment: It depends. Do you want the .boxcaption hidden when javascript is enabled or not? If so, use CSS to hide it. If not, use javascript.

Comment: Maybe the reason I'm not seeing it work the first time is because the CSS is faster than the JS. So maybe I need to prevent the psudo:hover on non-wekit browsers.

Comment: Try this now. You'll see that it still doesn't animate the first time. http://jsfiddle.net/SXX2D/17/

Comment: Well, if you uncomment the line I added, it does animate correctly. Not sure what the issue is here, it works fine for me. GL.

Answer (score 2):

Add Below CSS Code To Your Page :

```
.boxgrid .boxcaption {
     display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not supposed to animate when you first hover over it (unless you have set it to have `display: none` in the CSS somewhere).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VmAwa/).